# How to loop here to print the first image if wrong and the second if two times wrong?

Tags: javascript

I want to print the new hangman image each time the user fails to guess consecutively, I dont know how to code that if the user fails one letter print the second image(head), if the user failes two (show the body) and so on... I dont see how i can do that, with if inside another if? With switch statement?

```js
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
var start  = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[3];
var result = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[2];
var image = document.getElementById('image');

//I PICK WORD
var wordComputer = prompt('INSERT A WORD');
var wc = wordComputer.split('');
console.log(wc);

start.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  //PLAYER PICK LETTER
  var wordPlayer = prompt('INSERT YOUR LETTER');
  var wp = wordPlayer.split('');
  if (wp[0] === wc[0] || wp[0] === wc[1] || wp[0] === wc[2] || wp[0] === wc[3] || wp[0] === wc[4] || wp[0] === wc[5] || wp[0] === wc[6] || wp[0] === wc[7]) {
    result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + wp;
    result.style.fontSize = '50px';
    result.style.color = 'green';
    result.style.textTransform = 'capitalize';
    console.log(1);

  } else if (wp[0] !== wc[0] || wp[0] !== wc[1] || wp[0] !== wc[2] || wp[0] !== wc[3] || wp[0] !== wc[4] || wp[0] !== wc[5] || wp[0] !== wc[6] || wp[0] !== wc[7]){
    result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + wp;
    result.style.fontSize = '50px';
    result.style.color = 'red';
    result.style.textTransform = 'capitalize';
    image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/hangman2.png)';
    console.log(2);

  } else if (wp[0] !== wc[0] && wp[0] !== wc[1] && wp[0] !== wc[2] && wp[0] !== wc[3] + wp[0] !== wc[0] && wp[0] !== wc[1] && wp[0] !== wc[2] && wp[0] !== wc[3]) {
    image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/hangman3.png)';
    console.log(3);
  }

});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

 h1:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(5deg);
}

header > h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}


.wrapper{
  max-width: 680px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.left{
  /*max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 300px;*/
  float: left;
  /*margin: 60px 0 ;*/
  width: 50%

}
.right{
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
}

/*img{
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
}*/

.result{
  width: 550px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin:  auto 0px auto;;*/
}

.start{
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#imagen{
  background-image: url("images/hangman1.png");
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HANGMAN</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>HANGMAN</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main>
      <section class="left">
        <div id="image">
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="right">INSTRUCTION
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="result">
      </div>
      <div class="start">START
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Count the number of errors. If there is at least one show the image `"hangman" + numberOfErrors + ".png"`